# Java socket not sending data when on terminal

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, command-line

I am developing a chat application in java and i am facing a problem with the deployment.
Even though my application runs smoothly when executed via an IDE (server in IntelliJ and Client in Netbeans) when i try to run the server via terminal the server is not working properly. By not properly i mean that the server is recieving messeges from the user but it doesn't respond back.

For example, the first three steps the client executes are:

- Login
- Get User List
- Get Group List

Even though the server is recieving these messages/requests it doesnt respond back.

I assign each connection to the server to a new thread because that's a multiclient application.

Any idea what is going on?

Here is an example picture of what the output is in terminal:

[image]

[image]

and then the server is hanging there.

**Server Implementation**

Here is the code for starting the server.

```
public class ThreadedServer {

ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket welcomeSocket = null;

public ThreadedServer() {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ServerConfiguration.SERVER_PORT);
        System.out.println("Server started");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            welcomeSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted: " + welcomeSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + welcomeSocket.getLocalPort());
            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientConnection(welcomeSocket));
            t.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

}
```

This is the client connection class where i handle the messeges i recieve and i send the messeges i want.

public class ClientConnection implements Runnable {

```
private final Socket clientSocket;
private DataInputStream dis;
private DataOutputStream dos;

private int sessionId;
private int userId;
private String username;
private ClientConnection self;

public ClientConnection(Socket client) {
    this.clientSocket = client;
    this.self = this;
}

public DataOutputStream getOutputStream() {
    return dos;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Client Thread started!");
    initializeDataStreams();
    startListeningForMessages();

}

private void initializeDataStreams() {
    try {
        dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Server: Initialized Streams");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


private void startListeningForMessages() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String message;

                while ((message = dis.readUTF()) != null) {
                    System.err.println("Recieved from client: " + message);
                    if (ServerConfiguration.LOG_COMMUNICATION_MESSAGES) {
                        System.out.println("client message string recieved \" "
                                + message + " \"");
                    }
                    processMessage(message);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // 1) Remove the connection from the list of connections.
                ConnectionManager.getInstance().removeConnection(self);
                // 2) Inform database for logout time AND Error Messege!
                DatabaseAction.logout(sessionId, "Unknown Error occurred");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void processMessage(String messege) {
    Messege inbound = new Gson().fromJson(messege, Messege.class);
    if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.login) {
        performLogin(inbound);
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.logout) {
        performLogout(inbound);
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.simple_messege) {
        sendMessege(inbound);
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.group_messege) {
        sendGroupMessege(inbound);
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.get_all_users) {
        getAllUsers();
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.get_groups_im_involved_in) {
        getGroupsImInvolvedIn();
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.get_messeges_from_user) {
        getMessegesFromUser(inbound);
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.get_messeges_from_group) {
        getMessegesFromGroup(inbound);
    } else if (inbound.getType() == MessegeType.create_new_group) {
        createNewGroup(inbound);
    }
}


private void sendGroupMessege(Messege inbound) {
    new SendGroupMessegeAction(this, inbound);
}

public void close() {
    try {
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void performLogin(Messege messege) {
    LoginAction la = new LoginAction(messege.getUser(), messege, this);
    this.username = messege.getUser();
    this.sessionId = la.getSessionId();
    this.userId = la.getUserId();
}

private void performLogout(Messege messege) {
    new LogoutAction(this, messege);
}

public void sendMessege(Messege messege) {
    new SendSimpleMessegeAction(this, messege);
}

public int getSessionId() {
    return sessionId;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

private void getAllUsers() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending all users to client " + username);
        UsersObject uo = DatabaseAction.getAllUsers(userId);
        GetAllUsersMessege gaum = new GetAllUsersMessege(uo.getUsernames(), uo.areOnline(), uo.getHasSentMessegesThatAreUnread());
        Messege m = new Messege("", MessegeType.get_all_users, new Gson().toJson(gaum));
        System.out.println("Sent from server: " + new Gson().toJson(m));
        dos.writeUTF(new Gson().toJson(m));
        dos.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the connection to the server from the **Client side**

```
public class ServerConnection {

DataInputStream dis;
static DataOutputStream dos;
Socket socket;

public static ServerConnection instance;

public static ServerConnection getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ServerConnection();
    }
    return instance;
}

private ServerConnection() {
    initializeConnection();
    startListeningThread();
}

private void initializeConnection() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(MyStatics.server_address, 3333);
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Client: Connection Initialized");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerConnection.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void startListeningThread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String line = "";
                while (!socket.isClosed() && (line = dis.readUTF()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Recieved from Server: " + line);
                    Messege m = new Gson().fromJson(line, Messege.class);
                    processMessege(m);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
//                    Logger.getLogger(ServerConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                if (!ex.getMessage().equals("Socket closed")) {
                    `enter code here`Logger.getLogger(ServerConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void processMessege(Messege m) {
    if (m.getType() == MessegeType.get_all_users) {
        GetAllUsersMessege gaum = new Gson().fromJson(m.getEnv(), GetAllUsersMessege.class);
        MainWindow.usersData = gaum.getUsers();
        MainWindow.usersOnline = gaum.getOnline();
        MainWindow.usersWhoSentSomething = gaum.getHasSentMessegesThatAreUnread();
        MainWindow.changeData();
    } else if (m.getType() == MessegeType.get_groups_im_involved_in) {
        GetGroupsImInvolvedInMessege ggiiim = new Gson().fromJson(m.getEnv(), GetGroupsImInvolvedInMessege.class);
        MainWindow.groupsData = ggiiim.getGroups();
        MainWindow.changeData();
    } else if (m.getType() == MessegeType.simple_messege) {
        SimpleMessege sm = new Gson().fromJson(m.getEnv(), SimpleMessege.class);
        MainWindow.informThatMessegeIsRecieved(m.getUser());
        System.out.println("Recieved simple messege");
        for (ChatBox chatBox : MyInstances.chatBoxes) {
            if (chatBox.getTo().equals(m.getUser())) {
                System.out.println("Chatbox was found");
                chatBox.appendRecievedMessege(sm.getMessege());
            }
        }

   ...
   ...
    }
 }
```

EDIT: I added code snippets.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the responsible code. Without the exact way on how your Server handles the connection we cannot help you properly.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues(not sure):
0) About `readUTF`, and `writeUTF`
IDE may calling the server and client in a charset(probably UTF-8), while in terminal you don't set it, so it inherits from OS.

In your terminal, set the charset to UTF-8 (for both server and client) and try again. e.g. (`java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar <<your jar server/client>>`)

Also if you always send plain String from server and client (no primitive/binary), so you may using `BufferedReader` and `PrintStream`/`PrintStream` instead of `DataInputReader` and Writer.

1) To make you sure you are running the latest/correct file, in netbeans always right-click on project and go for a clean and build operation.

Hope it helps.